# How declare and import variable into component on angular 2 webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I try to declare variable into some `*.ts` file and import file into component `.ts` file to use.

`url.ts`:

```
var loginComponentTemplateUrl: string;
if (true) {
    loginComponentTemplateUrl = './login.component.html';
} else {
    loginComponentTemplateUrl = './app/login/login.component.html';
}
```

`login.component.ts`:

```
import './url';
@Component({
    templateUrl: loginComponentTemplateUrl
})
...
```

In `SystemJS` all working, but when I try to use `Webpack` build an error: `loginComponentTemplateUrl variable not defined`.
I need to import this `url.ts` file into `polyfills.ts` or `vendor.ts` but how? as I understand `vendor.ts/polyfills.ts` files working only with `modules`.

Comment: share your webpack.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `export` the `loginComponentTemplateUrl` variable from `url.ts` and `import` it in `login.component.ts`

something like this in `url.ts`

```
let loginComponentTemplateUrl: string;
if (true) { //will throw linting error
   loginComponentTemplateUrl = './login.component.html';
} else {
    loginComponentTemplateUrl = './app/login/login.component.html';
}

export default loginComponentTemplateUrl
```

And, in `login.component.ts`

```
import loginComponentTemplateUrl from './url'
@Component({
     templateUrl: loginComponentTemplateUrl
})
...
```

Comment: can I some how in one file make multiple: export default ?

Comment: You can do multiple exports but default should be only one. By the way, is that answer helped? then accept this answer

Comment: nope. still not working on Webpack build. Browser shows variable value but tmplate not loading.