# How write single url for angular 2 component templateUrl for SystemJS and Webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, systemjs

I find out that for `SystemJS` and Webpack project builds in `Angular2 @Component templateUrls` string must be different.

For SystemJS:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home'
    templateUrl: './app/home/home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ...
}
```

For Webpack:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home'
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ...
}
```

For `SystemJS` build `templateUrl` string must be full path from root. For `Webpack` `templateUrl` must be non full path from root (html template for component and component description `*.ts` file located in one location). It is possible to write single templateUrl string for `SystemJS` and `Webpack`? For mutch quicker switch beetwen `SystemJS/Webpack`. I try to use variable string for `templateUrl`:

```
import { loginComponentTemplateUrl } from '../shared/url-routing-provider';

@Component({
    templateUrl: loginComponentTemplateUrl 
})
```

`url-routing-provider.ts`:

```
export var systemjs: boolean = true;
export var loginComponentTemplateUrl: string = (systemjs) ? './login.component.html' : './app/login/login.component.html';
export default systemjs;
```

For `SystemJS` it works (for AMD pattern), but for `Webpack` not. My previos post related for this: [How declare and import variable into component on angular 2 webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150137/how-declare-and-import-variable-into-component-on-angular-2-webpack#40152068)

Answer (score 0):

To use relative paths with systemJs module loader you can [set the moduleId](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html#!#set-the-moduleid-). This trick, however, does not work when you switch to webpack, which uses numeric module identifier.

A solution that works for **both** webpack and system.js:

```
@Component({
   moduleId: typeof module.id == "string" ? module.id : null,
   selector: 'home'
   templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ...
}
```

It works, but I cannot tell it is pretty.