# How to make an Angular 2 library of components compatible with webpack.js and system.js?

Tags: angular, webpack, components, systemjs

I'm doing my first Angular 2 library. For the moment, it's just a library of components. I would like a library compatible with Webpack and SystemJS. I managed to write a first component with a code compatible with SystemJs and rewrite the code to be compatible with Webpack but which is the right code to force it to be compatible with both ?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  moduleId: typeof module.id == "string" ? module.id : null,
  templateUrl: 'foo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['foo.component.css']
})
export class FooComponent {
 logo: String;
 name: String;
 constructor() {
  this.logo = '';
  this.name = 'My name';
 }
}
```

For the moment I found [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257238/how-write-single-url-for-angular-2-component-templateurl-for-systemjs-and-webpac) to resolve a part of the relative path problem. That works with systemJS but I have still this error with a project using Webpack :

```
Cannot GET /application.component.html
Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load foo.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load  foo.component.html undefined
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load foo.component.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on the npm package [ng2-inline-require](https://github.com/Oversan/ng2-inline-require). This tool compile scss and html external files and inject the code in the **styles** and **template** attributes which are compatible with SystemJS and Webpack.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'foo',
 moduleId: typeof module.id == "string" ? module.id : null,
 template: require('./foo.component.html'),
 styles: [ require('./foo.component.css') ]
})
export class FooComponent {
 logo: String;
 name: String;

 constructor() {
   this.logo = '';
   this.name = 'My name';
 }
}
```

and compile it like this :

```
ng2-inline-require -i ./src/foo.component.ts -o ./dist/foo.component.ts
```